# Prime Factorisation in Swift

Tags: primes, swift, iteration

I made a playground to try find prime factors of any given number, and it works, and I'm happy with the first function, even if not correctly named - I don't know what to name it.

My main need for improvement is in the second half. I can't for the life of me think of a way of looping through a list until the functions output is constant. I thought of recursion, but I didn't understand it. This is what I came up with, and I'd like to see how I can improve it because it's sloppy and ugly.

```
import UIKit

func primeFact(tree: [Int]) -> Array<Int> {
    var newTree = tree
    for element in newTree{
        for divisor in 2..<element{
            if element%divisor == 0{
                newTree = newTree.filter { $0 != element}
                newTree+=[(element/divisor),divisor]
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return newTree
}

var initial = primeFact(tree: [992])
var temp = [Int]()
while true {
    if primeFact(tree: initial) == initial{
        break
    }
    temp = primeFact(tree: initial)
    initial = temp
}
print(primeFact(tree: initial))
```

Answer (score 7):

To address your "main need" first: Your algorithm starts with a
single-element array, and then repeatedly calls `primeFact()` to
compute a new array, until the array is "constant". That can
be done more clearly as

```
var initial = [992]
var temp = [Int]()
repeat {
    temp = initial
    initial = primeFact(tree: temp)
} while initial != temp
print(initial)
```

However, your algorithms seems to be highly inefficient, for
the following reasons:

- Since the trial division starts with the lowest possible divisors,
  each found `divisor` is necessarily a prime number. But the
  next call to `primeFact()` will again try to find divisors of that
  number.
- All calls to `primeFact()` will try all numbers starting from 2
  as divisors for all elements in the "tree". For example, if the
  current list is `[2, 2, <someOddNumber>]` then each call will
  again try to divide `<someOddNumber>` by 2.
- A lot of intermediate arrays are created.
- Possible large arrays must be compared in order to determine if
  the factorization is done.

Additional remarks:

- Put spaces around operators, e.g. `element % divisor` for
  better readability.
- Use either `[Int]` or `Array<Int>` for array notation (I prefer
  the first), but don't mix it.
- Calling the parameter `tree` is confusing because you treat
  it as an array, not as a tree.

A more efficient approach is to divide the given number by 2, 3, 4, ...
As soon as a factor is found, the number is *divided* by this factor.
Using the fact that composite number \$ n > 1 \$
must have a prime factor \$ p \$ for which  \$ p \le \sqrt n \$,
this leads to the following function:

```
func primeFactors(_ n: Int) -> [Int] {
    var n = n
    var factors: [Int] = []

    var divisor = 2
    while divisor * divisor <= n {
        while n % divisor == 0 {
            factors.append(divisor)
            n /= divisor
        }
        divisor += divisor == 2 ? 1 : 2
    }
    if n > 1 {
        factors.append(n)
    }

    return factors
}
```

As another small optization, only 2 and all *odd* numbers are used
as trial divisors.

*Performance comparison:*

- For \$ N = 1000000000000 = 2^{12} \cdot 5^{12} \$:
  Your tree factorization: 1ms. Direct factorization: 0.005 ms.
- For \$ N = 1000000000001 = 73 \cdot 137 \cdot 99990001 \$:
  Your tree factorization: 1,100ms. Direct factorization: 0.1 ms.

The tests were done on a 1.2 GHz Intel Core m5 MacBook, with the
code compiled in Release mode.

Comment: I noticed that this line: `divisor = divisor == 2 ? 3 : divisor + 2` is very odd. You might replace it with `divisor += divisor == 2 ? 1 : 2`, if you consider it a good practice, because it slightly improves readability (IMO)

Comment: @DaniSpringer: You are “blocking the main thread.” The UI is only updated when program control returns to the main event loop. Longer calculations must be done on a background thread.

Comment: Addendum: Looking for prime factors could be [sped up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53023939/2907715) by only looking for numbers off by `1` from a multiple of 6.

Answer (score 4):

`import UIKit` is superfluous.

Your algorithm is hugely inefficient: you are rebuilding the array many times.  Swift Playground says that when factoring 992, the line with `newTree = newTree.filter { $0 != element}` executes 38 times.

This algorithm doesn't involve rewriting the array, and it also outputs the prime factors in non-decreasing order.

```
func primeFactors(n: Int) -> Array<Int> {
    var n = n
    var factors = [Int]()
    for divisor in 2 ..< n {
        while n % divisor == 0 {
            factors.append(divisor)
            n /= divisor
        }
    }
    return factors
}

print(primeFactors(n: 992))
```